# Verify existence and uniqueness is satisfied for all x and t.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$\frac{dx}{dt}=(x-1)(x+4)\sin(t)+(x-1)$$ be be a non-linear non-separable first order differential equation.

(a)  Verify existence and uniqueness is satisfied for all $x$  and $t$.

(b)  Verify $x(t) = 1$ for all $t$ is a solution if  $x(t_0) = 1$.

(c)  Explain why any solution to this differential equation is either always one or never one.

I got part a) Since $f(t,x)$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$ are both continuous for all x and t they satisfy the Existence Uniqueness Theorem.

How do I go about part b), do I just take $x(t)=1$, find its derivative and check if it works?

Also can anyone explain part c).

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Edit: After some though I think I figure out b), since the differential equation satisfies the Existence-Uniqueness Theorem for all x and t, then it must satisfy it for the initial condition of $x(t_0)=1$. This means that there is one and only one solution for this initial condition. Since $x(t)=1$ for all t including $t_0$, it would be sufficient to show that $x(t)=1$ is a solution to the DE to prove the statement. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For b), yes, you only have to check the constant $1$ is a solution.

For c), you have to prove that if $x(t)$ can take the value $1$, it IS the constant function $1$ of b). Think of uniqueness.

Comment: I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct here, but here is what I think. For all initial conditions $x(t_0)=1$, we have that the only solution is $x(t)=1$ by Existence Uniqueness. This means that for any other initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0, x_0 \neq 1$, the solution $x(t) \neq 1$ since it would violate Existence-Uniqueness. Therefore, the solution to the DE is always one or never one. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You should add, from my point of view, that if a solution takes the value $1$ for *some* value of $t$, this value may be set as the initial value t_0$, hence $x(t)=1$ for *all* $t$ by b).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to give a help!